# How to move Z up after printing in Cura?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

Simple question, I want to move my printer head up when the print finishes instead of to the side.
Where's the option to do this in Cura?

Comment: Does it have a Custom G-code section, where you could add the command to the End G-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go towards the right top corner. Click on the printer name. From the drop down, select, "Manage printers". You will get a dialogue box in the middle of your screen. Your current printer's name will be shown in italics. On the right side of the dialogue box, click on, "Machine settings". This will open another dialogue box. In the lower left, you will see a text box with the heading, "End G-Code" scroll down to where you see the line, "`G1 X0 Y0`". This is the line that moves your print head to the lower left corner. `G1` is the command for a linear move. `X0` and `Y0` are move instructions to move the the 0 coordinate for the two axes. Change this line to `G1 Znn` where "nn" is the number of the coordinate you wish to move to. Close this dialogue, close the previous dialogue and all newly sliced file will now use this code.

If like to keep track of any changes you make, you can put a semi-colon at the beginning of the line. This turns the line into a comment and will not be actioned. Then press enter and on a new line, put the line, `G1 znn`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know the Gcode for relative move? Like ”move Z 10 from where it is?

Comment: That would be `G91`. You can get all the G-Codes here [link](https://marlinfw.org/meta/gcode/).